# Full-featured web server (cPanel, Softaculous) running under VMware for multiple projects?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, wordpress, lamp

I love working on WordPress installations locally, mainly because of the speed. No lag, no overworked web hosts. Super-snappy, instant response.

I found quite a few ready-to-use solutions in the form of pre-built appliances, such as Bitnami WordPress running in vmWare under Windows. However:

- I can only run one WordPress installation
- The site url is something like http:/10.1.10.1/wordpress

What I'd like:

- Run multiple installations of WordPress, easy setup
- Have the appliance respond to a full domain name, such as www.mysite.com if I add an entry to my hosts file to resolve mysite.com to the appliance's IP.

My dream solution would be an appliance that has cPanel and Softaculous and pretty much behaves exactly like a shared hosting account somewhere. Without much Linux knowledge, i don't even know where to begin.

- Is such an appliance available for download anywhere? or,
- Is anyone willing to build one (for free, for money, for barter etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not need much Linux knowledge to implement something like this yourself. Even if you started with a pre-build LAMP image all you'd need to do is learn how to add virtual hosts to your apache configuration and create MySQL databases. In fact it sounds like a great project to begin to learn basic linux server administration.

Some documentation links to get you started:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html

If you wanted to be a bit more adventurous you might also attempt to install Apache, MySQL and PHP yourself. Even this is not too difficult as most distros come with a package manager which will be able to install these for you with a single command.

Having a whole cPanel + Softaculous setup would seem overkill if all you wanted to do was setup wordpress installations.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. While I completely agree with what you're suggesting, I truly feel that having a "1-click solution" will work out better in the long run. It's not just me doing the installations, and utmost ease/convenience is the top priority. So far, I found this: http://virtual-machine.org/centos-6-x86_64-64bit-vmware-image-download and it's beautiful :) as it even has a GUI. But from there, to the point of just typing mymachine.com:2083 into the browser seems like a long way to go. How much time would an experienced server administrator need to build this "dream setup"?